# Silently refresh power query on Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, m

In Excel 2013 I used the following VBA sub to silently refresh a table loaded using power query:

```
Public Sub RefreshData()
    Sheet1.Range("my_data_table").ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
End Sub
```

After migration to Excel 2016 the same code have different behaviour, meaning that after the data has been loaded it changes the view to the fresh data table.

Is there a way to get the old behaviour back?

Edit:
I made a model that describes the problem more accurately, can be downloaded:[here](http://isdv.dc-host.ro/Dropbox/1.xlsm)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "*it changes the view*". Probably a screenshot could help.

Comment: I have a button on another sheet which triggers the refresh. With Excel 2016 after refresh the view is changed to the data table, doesn't work silently anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can only turn off screen updating and switch back to your original sheet.

```
Public Sub RefreshData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet1.Range("my_data_table").ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
    DoEvents 'let refresh finish first
    Worksheets("SheetNameWhereRefershButtonIs").Activate 'switch back to a specific sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Or as @Chronocidal pointed out:

```
Public Sub RefreshData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Sheet1.Range("my_data_table").ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
        DoEvents 'let refresh finish first
        .Activate 'switch back to original sheet
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually 1 case where I'd argue for `ActiveSheet`, due to the fact that the `With` constructor is not reevaluated if the object changes: `With ActiveSheet: Sheet1.Range("my_data_table").ListObject.TableObject.Refresh: .Activate: End With`

Comment: @Chronocidal you are right, this might really be an option here. Nevertheless I try to avoid `ActiveSheet` when explaining things because it is used wrong so often. But I included your suggestion. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I think it sould be a cleaner solution to this. Let's wait a litle bit, if nobody can find it I'll mark your's as answer.

Comment: As an explanation, I try to avoid as much as possible `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` because if code fails in the middle it would not rich the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` point.

Comment: @SorinGFS No reason to avoid `ScreenUpdating`, it can easily avoided staying off by a good error handling (which should be included anyway) where you switch it back on as soon as an error occurs.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ the solution you wrote for Chronocidal does not work

Comment: @Pᴇʜ from the solution you wrote for Chronocidal I see that `Sheet1.Range("my_data_table").ListObject.TableObject.Refresh` actually changes the active sheet!

Comment: @SorinGFS you will probably need a `DoEvents` right after the refresh then to let it finish first. See my edit.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ nope. It gives an exception: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Comment: @SorinGFS That should not happen by just adding a `DoEvents`. No idea why this doesn't work.